# Right Click on Macbook 7.1 (Ubuntu 12.10)?

Tags: 12.10, touchpad, macbook, apple, trackpad

There's two things I love: Ubuntu and my Macbook. Unfortunately the right click (= click with two fingers) is just a real pain. Is there a way to have my right click in the right bottom corner of my Trackpad? I use Ubuntu 12.10.